# Convert yy.mmd(d) date format to yyyy-mm-dd in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I am working with an old date format where the first two digits represent the year in the 20th century. The first two decimal places are the month (i.e. 01-12) and the third and fourth decimal place are the day of the month (i.e., 01-31). The issue is that days ending in zero (i.e., 10, 20, 30) have the trailing zero dropped such that some date formats only have three decimal places.

How can I restore the trailing zero so that I can convert this old date format into a modern date format (i.e., yyyy-mm-dd)?

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Example data

xx <- data.frame(yr_mo_da = c('89.1208','89.1209','89.121', '89.1211'))

# My attempt to extract year, month, day from the old date format
# NOTE how the day is not extracted properly because there is not a fourth decimal place on Dec. 10

xx$year <- as.numeric(gsub("\\..*","",xx$yr_mo_da))
xx$month <- as.numeric(sub("^[0-9]+\\.([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", xx$yr_mo_da))
xx$day <- as.numeric(sub("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", xx$yr_mo_da))
xx
#>   yr_mo_da year month    day
#> 1  89.1208   89    12  8.000
#> 2  89.1209   89    12  9.000
#> 3   89.121   89    12 89.121
#> 4  89.1211   89    12 11.000

# Create modern date format

xx <- xx %>%
  mutate(year = year + 1900,
         Date = make_date(year,month,day)) %>%
  select(-c(yr_mo_da,year,day,month))
xx
#>         Date
#> 1 1989-12-08
#> 2 1989-12-09
#> 3       <NA>
#> 4 1989-12-11
```

The correct output should look like this:

```r
xx
#>         Date
#> 1 1989-12-08
#> 2 1989-12-09
#> 3 1989-12-10
#> 4 1989-12-11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: use `lubridate::ymd` ie `lubridate::ymd(xx$yr_mo_da)`

Comment: If the assumptions hold, you can do `str_pad(x, "right", 7, "0")` which will append a 0 to all six digit strings, then apply any date xfrms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first right-pad those strings with "0":

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

xx <- data.frame(yr_mo_da = c('89.1208','89.1209','89.121', '89.1211'))
xx |> 
  mutate(yr_mo_da_pad = str_pad(yr_mo_da, width = max(str_length(yr_mo_da)), side = "right", pad = "0"),
         date = ymd(yr_mo_da_pad))
#>   yr_mo_da yr_mo_da_pad       date
#> 1  89.1208      89.1208 1989-12-08
#> 2  89.1209      89.1209 1989-12-09
#> 3   89.121      89.1210 1989-12-10
#> 4  89.1211      89.1211 1989-12-11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the numeric data back to text before parsing. One way with just base R is this:

```
> xx <- data.frame(yr_mo_da = c('89.1208','89.1209','89.121', '89.1211'))  
> xx$year <- trunc(as.numeric(xx$yr_mo_da))
> xx$moda <- (as.numeric(xx$yr_mo_da) - xx$year)*10000
> xx$date <- strptime(sprintf("%02.0f%04.0f", xx$year, xx$moda), "%y%m%d")
> xx
  yr_mo_da year moda       date
1  89.1208   89 1208 1989-12-08
2  89.1209   89 1209 1989-12-09
3   89.121   89 1210 1989-12-10
4  89.1211   89 1211 1989-12-11
>
```

If you original assignment didn't force character values we could skip the double `as.numeric()`.